# Android After capturing image camera is reopened in LG phone works fine on other devices

Tags: android, android-camera

This works fine on almost every device but reopens camera once the image captured and user presses save.

**Launch Camera:**

```
private void launchCamera() {

    try
    {   
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        File file = getFilePath(2);
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("Exception ", e.toString());
    }
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

    try {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:

                try{

                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

                    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    break;

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("Exception ", e.toString());
                }

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("Exception ", e.toString());
    }
}
```

**Create Temp File path:**

```
private File getFilePath(int type) {

    File mediaFile = null;

    try{
        File mediaStorageDir = null;

        Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

        if(isSDPresent) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MyFolder";

            mediaStorageDir = new File(path);

            if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
                if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                    Log.v("Exception ", "failed to create directory");
                    return mediaFile;
                }
            }
        } else {
            mediaStorageDir = appContext.getDir("MyFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }

        if (type == 2){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "MyFolder_IMG_"+ String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()) + ".png");
        } 
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.v("Exception ", e.toString());
    } 
    return mediaFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine on almost every device

At best, it "works fine" for the devices that you have tried, and for the camera apps that you have tried on those devices. There are over 10,000 Android device models, and there are hundreds of camera apps on the Play Store. That leads to millions of combinations.

*Ideally*, the activity launched by `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` would return control to your app, via `setResult()` and `finish()`, after the user has taken a picture. However, there is no *requirement*, validated by any sort of approval process, that forces developers of camera apps to return control to you after the user has taken a picture.

Your options are either to live with the behavior as it stands, advising users to press BACK if needed to return to your app, or to skip `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and implement your own logic to take a picture with the camera.

Comment: This happens with gallery feature as well. After image selection the gallery is reopened, but only on LG phone.

Comment: @androidify: "only on LG phone" -- no, it happens only on the LG phone(s) that you have tested, and only with the "gallery" applications that you have tested.

Comment: Is there any solution to fix this issue? Not only LG phone but also another phone XTOUCH that is also another android phone has the same issue. But works fine on Nexus 7, HTC phones, Samsung Phones.

Comment: @androidify: "Is there any solution to fix this issue?" -- the only "issue" is with your expectations. While what you want is rational, it is not *required*. Developers of phones, camera apps, and gallery apps are welcome to do the unexpected. This is no different than you including a link to a page on somebody else's Web site from your Web site, and expecting that page to always exist. *Maybe* that page will exist forever, but Web sites are welcome to discontinue pages and return 404 errors for those links. If you link to a third-party app or page, the third party can do what it wants.